# How can i modify FASTA headers in a multi fasta file using BioPython SeqIO

Tags: fasta, python

I have a multi fasta file similar to this (relatively new here so uncertain of best way to present this; I have gone for an output and the code i used to make it - belt and braces...):

```
# create a test dataset
with open('test_dat.txt', 'w') as test_dat:
    l1 = [">AAA a aa", ">BBB b bb", ">CCC c cc"]
    l2 = ["ATGATG", "GACGAC", "TTGTTG"]

    for i in range(len(l1)):
        test_dat.write(l1[i] + "\n")
        test_dat.write(l2[i] + "\n")

# which outputs something like this
>AAA a aa
ATGATG
>BBB b bb
GACGAC
>CCC c cc
TTGTTG
```

I want to modify the fasta headers in my fasta file by adding some text to the beginning and, ideally, stripping out spaces (as i was advised that white space in the headings could cause problems for me down the line). My plan was to do this using BioPython and SeqIO.

I started like this:

```
# my attempt at altering the fasta headers using SeqIO
from Bio import SeqIO

# open my test data and create an output file
with open('test_dat.txt', 'r') as inputs, open('test_dat_out.txt', 'w') as outputs:

    # create dictionary of the fasta sequences using SeqIO
    my_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(inputs, "fasta"))

    # renaming my fasta headers - adding "TEST~~~TEST~~~" to front of header and remove white space
    for v in my_dict.values(): # using the values() to loop through...
        v.description = "TEST~~~TEST~~~" + v.description.replace(" ", "_")

    # write result to file
    SeqIO.write(my_dict.values(), outputs, 'fasta')
```

which gave me a result with some duplication in the fasta header:

```
#result i want
>TEST~~~TEST~~~AAA_a_aa
ATGATG

#result i get
>AAA TEST~~~TEST~~~AAA_a_aa
ATGATG
```

If i modify both the `.id` and `.description` in exactly the same way, as suggested [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/307/changing-the-record-id-in-a-fasta-file-using-biopython), but **without** removing white space:

```
# renaming my fasta headers - adding "TEST~~~TEST~~~" to front of header
    for v in my_dict.values(): # using the values() to loop through...
        v.id = "TEST~~~TEST~~~" + v.id
        v.description = "TEST~~~TEST~~~" + v.description
```

I get almost what i want, but the header still has spaces:

```
>TEST~~~TEST~~~AAA a aa
ATGATG
```

I have tried to make the `.id` and `.description` match by adding a "_" to the end of `.id`, or by adding `.replace(" ", "_")` to both `.id` and `.description` (despite there being no spaces in `.id`), but I just cant seem to get exactly the output i want.

I would really appreciate any pointers on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close, but unfortunately for legacy reasons this aspect of the Biopython parser is not very intuitive. The key point is the `.id` is anything up until the first white space character. One day I hope the `.description` and `.id` attributes are replaced by a single attribute like `.header`. Anyway, here is a solution for your case:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

to_add = "TEST~~~TEST~~~"

with open("out.fa", "w") as outputs:
    for r in SeqIO.parse("in.fa", "fasta"):
        r.id = (to_add + r.description).replace(" ", "_")
        r.description = r.id
        SeqIO.write(r, outputs, "fasta")
```

Output on your sample input:

```
>TEST~~~TEST~~~AAA_a_aa
ATGATG
>TEST~~~TEST~~~BBB_b_bb
GACGAC
>TEST~~~TEST~~~CCC_c_cc
TTGTTG
```

Comment: Much appreciated @Chris_Rands.  So my problem was that as soon as i removed all white space characters from the .description, the description - in its entirety - is considered to be the .id.